# How to correctly import multi grade project in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm unable to correctly import an existing grade project with the following structure:

```
containing_folder/
    build/
        build.gradle
        settings.gradle
    bluewhale/
```

where build.grade contains:

```
task waterhello << { task -> println "I'm $task.project.name" }

project(':bluewhale') {
    task bluewhalehello << {task -> println "I'm $task.project.name" }
}
```

and settings.gradle contains:

```
includeFlat 'bluewhale'
```

When I import this project in intelliJ IDEA 15 and try to run the following task from the :bluewhale context:
[image: intelliJ task selection]

I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'bluewhalehello' not found in root project 'bluewhale'.
```

If i try to run it from terminal by executing

```
gradle bluewhale:bluewhalehello
```

it works just fine. Is there anything i can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use open option instead of import. Then just show the folder directory where build and settings gradle file is located. Intellij takes care of the rest